# When to change nz() function to COALESCE function?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have my Access table linked to SQL server. I have created linked view where I have replaced the `nz() function` with `COALESCE function`. However, I am not sure if I have to convert `nz function` to `COALESCE` in `VBA` as well.

For example for the code below:

`rst.Open "SELECT * FROM table1", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnl`y

I have

```
IF NZ('Field1',0) =0 then 

//do something
```

Should I do

```
IF COALESCE('Field1',0) =0 then 

//do something
```

Or do I only need to change it in my SQL query?

Comment: IIF and ISNULL are available in both. IIF is in later versions of SQL Server but you can still use IF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Coalesce` is a feature only available in `T-SQL` it *isn't* a VBA function.

It's up to you how you want to handle converting nulls into a new value, there are many ways to do this. You can check your variables before adding them to a SQL statement, or, you can alter them as part of the SQL with `Coalesce`, `IsNull` or `Case`.

Personally, I would do whatever is less code that still gets the idea across clearly. I'd imagine this would be decided on a case by case basis depending what it is you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd stick with the NZ() function in Access, and if you want to handle this on the SQL Server side, before pulling it into Access, that's another option.  In SQL Server, The COALESCE() function returns the first non-null value in a list.